# Understanding Android Service by example

Tags: android, service

I have an app that plays an song displaying its lyrics on the screen.

Two situations:

1. When the song is loaded from a local mp3 file.
2. When the song is loaded from remote location via internet

My understanding is that Android Service comes to rescue when the song is streamed from remote location via internet. Android Service helps here because of the i/o overheads involved. In the first case, where the song is played form local location, services is perhaps an overkill. I can simply play the music loading it in the activity and use MediaPlayer API to play it.

Is this understanding correct? Am I missing anything?

**Update:** The song size is over 10MB. So when you stream it via a slow internet over phone there might be some buffering and stuff to be accommodated for better user experience.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is this understanding correct?" -- not really. "services is perhaps an overkill" -- for the same song, there is roughly the same amount of I/O in both scenarios. Whether you use a service in this case will be dictated in large part based upon what you want to have happen if the user leaves your UI while music playback is going on.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated the question with the context of file size and internet connection speed as use case. I can safely assume that the file played locally is faster than a file that requires to be streamed over internet. The i/o isn't really the same. There are a number of factors you take into account when streaming something via internet right?

Comment: "The i/o isn't really the same" -- a three-minute song takes three minutes, regardless of whether the song is stored locally or streamed. There is a lot less bandwidth usage if the song is stored locally. I would guess that there is a bit less CPU usage if the song is stored locally. There will be less battery usage if the song is stored locally. None of that matters in terms of whether or not a service is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different `Services` for different use cases. For a `Media Player` it depends if you want to have the playback continuously playing in the back- or foreground.

So both cases are applicable for a `Media Player Service`. But the [Android Developer Guide Media Player Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices) outshines my answer

> Using a Service with MediaPlayer
>   If you want your media to play in the background even when your application is not onscreen—that is, you want it to continue playing while the user is interacting with other applications—then you must start a Service and control the MediaPlayer instance from there. You should be careful about this setup, because the user and the system have expectations about how an application running a background service should interact with the rest of the system. If your application does not fulfil those expectations, the user may have a bad experience. This section describes the main issues that you should be aware of and offers suggestions about how to approach them

Your second case is more a question about networking and in this case you could use a [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to download the `.mp3` and pass it to the [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Comment: In my Android OnePlus One phone, I'm able to start the app and let it play the song (code implemented, without services). Then I open a game app that plays its own background music. Interestingly enough, I hear both the song I played earlier along with the game's music. How is this happening? This incident is what prompted me to ask this question, changing my assumptions. Your help is appreciated.